# valueForKey: in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, objective-c, arrays, node.js, object

In Objective-C, if I have an array of objects and each object has a key of `id` like so:

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"id":@(1), @"name":@"Bob"}, @{@"id":@(2), @"name":@"Frank"}, @{@"id":@(3), @"name":@"Joe"}];
```

I could call `[array valueForKey:@"id"]` and get an array of just the ids.

How can I do this in Node/Javascript? If I set up my javascript array like this:

```
var array = [{"id":1, "name":"Bob"}, {"id":2, "name":"Frank"}, {"id":3, "name":"Joe"}];
```

I would like to be able to do this:

```
var idsArray = array.valueForKey("id");
```

How should I go about achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-array-of-javascript-objects

Comment: @MattWay, that link describes finding an object by ID, not getting a list of all IDs.

Comment: @BuckDoyle True. I didn't remove it however, because it is quite similar, and contains many good answers that would be worth reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` for that:

```
array.map(function (obj) { return obj.id; });
```

or if you have `underscore` in your project you can use `pluck`:

```
_.pluck(array, 'id');
```

Comment: Thanks! I've decided to switch to Underscore and have removed a lot of code in my project :)